# How to define instance variable through mixin

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a program like this:

```
module Filter
  def self.included?(klass)
    @count = 0
  end
end

class Object
  include Filter
end

class Person
  def get_count
    puts @count
  end
end
```

I want to define an instance variable @count through mixing Filter, hoping this mixin is accessible to all the Object.

However, my way doesn't work.

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: you want the variable to be the same for all objects or you just want to have all objets with this variable?

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares, I want to have all objects with this variable, not necessarily of the same value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a variable, use an attribute:

```
module Counter
  attr_accessor :count
end

class Person
  include Counter
end

person = Person.new
person.count = 50
puts person.count
```

Also, don't include stuff into `Object`, only include in your classes. Polluting the main namespace with non-general methods is bad and could lead to method name clashes in other classes, causing hard-to-find bugs.

Only include modules where you think they're needed, not everywhere.

Comment: The program in my post is just a example. Indeed, I want to add a method to every Object, so I think including the module in Object is a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

@HanXu, The solution from Maurício Linhares (as well as the suggestion to not pollute the main namespace) is the ideal way to go.

However, if you are *really* looking to change every instance of `Object`, then you might be able to just open the Object class and add the specific functionality you are looking for:

```
class Object
  attr_accessor :count
end

...

p = Person.new
p.count = 10
puts p.count    # => 10
```

Not recommended, but will work (in any case, you are opening Object to include the module now.)

Comment: OK, I think I should take your advise and rewrite my program. Thank you all very much!